# Output photos in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, data-science

Now I need to practice and build a recommender system by using R. Data set is from MovieLens. I want to output the movie photos as well, but not sure what to do. If there's 10000 movies, how should I save them and output them on my shiny APP? And suggestion is welcomed!

ui.R:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(proxy)
library(recommenderlab)
library(reshape2)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)
library(RCurl)

setwd("C:\\Users\\lili\\Movieshiny")
movies <- read.csv("movies.csv", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
movies <- movies[with(movies, order(title)), ]

ratings <- read.csv("ratings100k.csv", header = TRUE)


shinyUI(dashboardPage(skin="blue",
                      dashboardHeader(title = "Movie Recommenders"),
                      dashboardSidebar(
                        sidebarMenu(
                          menuItem("Movies", tabName = "movies", icon = icon("star-o")),
                          menuItem("About", tabName = "about", icon = icon("question-circle")),
                          menuItem("Source code", icon = icon("file-code-o"), 
                                   href = "https://github.com/danmalter/Movielense"),
                          menuItem(
                            list(

                              selectInput("select", label = h5("Select 3 Movies That You Like"),
                                          choices = as.character(movies$title[1:length(unique(movies$movieId))]),
                                          selectize = FALSE,
                                          selected = "Shawshank Redemption, The (1994)"),
                              selectInput("select2", label = NA,
                                          choices = as.character(movies$title[1:length(unique(movies$movieId))]),
                                          selectize = FALSE,
                                          selected = "Forrest Gump (1994)"),
                              selectInput("select3", label = NA,
                                          choices = as.character(movies$title[1:length(unique(movies$movieId))]),
                                          selectize = FALSE,
                                          selected = "Silence of the Lambs, The (1991)"),
                              submitButton("Submit")
                            )
                          )
                          )
                      ),


                      dashboardBody(
                        tags$head(
                          tags$style(type="text/css", "select { max-width: 360px; }"),
                          tags$style(type="text/css", ".span4 { max-width: 360px; }"),
                          tags$style(type="text/css",  ".well { max-width: 360px; }")
                        ),

                        tabItems(  
                          tabItem(tabName = "about",
                                  h2("About this App"),

                                  HTML('<br/>'),

                                  fluidRow(
                                    box(title = "Author: Danny Malter", background = "black", width=7, collapsible = TRUE,

                                        helpText(p(strong("This application a movie reccomnder using the movielense dataset."))),

                                        helpText(p("Please contact",
                                                   a(href ="https://twitter.com/danmalter", "Danny on twitter",target = "_blank"),
                                                   " or at my",
                                                   a(href ="http://danmalter.github.io/", "personal page", target = "_blank"),
                                                   ", for more information, to suggest improvements or report errors.")),

                                        helpText(p("All code and data is available at ",
                                                   a(href ="https://github.com/danmalter/", "my GitHub page",target = "_blank"),
                                                   "or click the 'source code' link on the sidebar on the left."
                                        ))
                                      )
                                  )
                            ),
                          tabItem(tabName = "movies",
                                  fluidRow(
                                    box(
                                      width = 6, status = "info", solidHead = TRUE,
                                      title = "Other Movies You Might Like",
                                      tableOutput("table")),
                                    valueBoxOutput("tableRatings1"),
                                    valueBoxOutput("tableRatings2"),
                                    valueBoxOutput("tableRatings3"),
                                    HTML('<br/>'),
                                    box(DT::dataTableOutput("myTable"), title = "Table of All Movies", width=12, collapsible = TRUE)
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )
              )
          )
```

server.R:

```
setwd("C:\\Users\\lili\\Movieshiny")
movies <- read.csv("movies.csv", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
movies <- movies[with(movies, order(title)), ]
ratings <- read.csv("ratings100k.csv", header = TRUE)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  # Text for the 3 boxes showing average scores
    formulaText1 <- reactive({
      paste(input$select)
    })
    formulaText2 <- reactive({
      paste(input$select2)
    })
    formulaText3 <- reactive({
      paste(input$select3)
    })

    output$movie1 <- renderText({
      formulaText1()
    })
    output$movie2 <- renderText({
      formulaText2()
    })
    output$movie3 <- renderText({
      formulaText3()
    })


    # Table containing recommendations
    output$table <- renderTable({

      # Filter for based on genre of selected movies to enhance recommendations
      cat1 <- subset(movies, title==input$select)
      cat2 <- subset(movies, title==input$select2)
      cat3 <- subset(movies, title==input$select3)

      # If genre contains 'Sci-Fi' then  return sci-fi movies 
      # If genre contains 'Children' then  return children movies
      if (grepl("Sci-Fi", cat1$genres) | grepl("Sci-Fi", cat2$genres) | grepl("Sci-Fi", cat3$genres)) {
        movies2 <- (movies[grepl("Sci-Fi", movies$genres) , ])
      } else if (grepl("Children", cat1$genres) | grepl("Children", cat2$genres) | grepl("Children", cat3$genres)) {
        movies2 <- movies[grepl("Children", movies$genres), ]
      } else {
        movies2 <- movies[grepl(cat1$genre1, movies$genres) 
                          | grepl(cat2$genre1, movies$genres)
                          | grepl(cat3$genre1, movies$genres), ]
      }

      movie_recommendation <- function(input,input2,input3){
        row_num <- which(movies2[,3] == input)
        row_num2 <- which(movies2[,3] == input2)
        row_num3 <- which(movies2[,3] == input3)
        userSelect <- matrix(NA,length(unique(ratings$movieId)))
        userSelect[row_num] <- 5 #hard code first selection to rating 5
        userSelect[row_num2] <- 4 #hard code second selection to rating 4
        userSelect[row_num3] <- 4 #hard code third selection to rating 4
        userSelect <- t(userSelect)

        ratingmat <- dcast(ratings, userId~movieId, value.var = "rating", na.rm=FALSE)
        ratingmat <- ratingmat[,-1]
        colnames(userSelect) <- colnames(ratingmat)
        ratingmat2 <- rbind(userSelect,ratingmat)
        ratingmat2 <- as.matrix(ratingmat2)

        #Convert rating matrix into a sparse matrix
        ratingmat2 <- as(ratingmat2, "realRatingMatrix")

        #Create Recommender Model
        recommender_model <- Recommender(ratingmat2, method = "UBCF",param=list(method="Cosine",nn=30))
        recom <- predict(recommender_model, ratingmat2[1], n=30)
        recom_list <- as(recom, "list")
        recom_result <- data.frame(matrix(NA,30))
        recom_result[1:30,1] <- movies2[as.integer(recom_list[[1]][1:30]),3]
        recom_result <- data.frame(na.omit(recom_result[order(order(recom_result)),]))
        recom_result <- data.frame(recom_result[1:10,])
        colnames(recom_result) <- "User-Based Collaborative Filtering Recommended Titles"
        return(recom_result)
      }

      movie_recommendation(input$select, input$select2, input$select3)

    })

    movie.ratings <- merge(ratings, movies)
    output$tableRatings1 <- renderValueBox({
      movie.avg1 <- summarise(subset(movie.ratings, title==input$select),
                              Average_Rating1 = mean(rating, na.rm = TRUE))
      valueBox(
        value = format(movie.avg1, digits = 3),
        subtitle = input$select,
        icon = if (movie.avg1 >= 3) icon("thumbs-up") else icon("thumbs-down"),
        color = if (movie.avg1 >= 3) "aqua" else "red"
      )

    })

    movie.ratings <- merge(ratings, movies)
    output$tableRatings2 <- renderValueBox({
      movie.avg2 <- summarise(subset(movie.ratings, title==input$select2),
                              Average_Rating = mean(rating, na.rm = TRUE))
      valueBox(
        value = format(movie.avg2, digits = 3),
        subtitle = input$select2,
        icon = if (movie.avg2 >= 3) icon("thumbs-up") else icon("thumbs-down"),
        color = if (movie.avg2 >= 3) "aqua" else "red"
      )
    })

    movie.ratings <- merge(ratings, movies)
    output$tableRatings3 <- renderValueBox({
      movie.avg3 <- summarise(subset(movie.ratings, title==input$select3),
                Average_Rating = mean(rating, na.rm = TRUE))
      valueBox(
        value = format(movie.avg3, digits = 3),
        subtitle = input$select3,
        icon = if (movie.avg3 >= 3) icon("thumbs-up") else icon("thumbs-down"),
        color = if (movie.avg3 >= 3) "aqua" else "red"
      )
    })


    # Generate a table summarizing each players stats
    output$myTable <- renderDataTable({
      movies[c("title", "genres")]
    })

}
)
```

For example, I want to insert this into my code:
library(shiny)

## Define UI with external image call

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Look at the image below"),

  sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(),

                mainPanel(htmlOutput("picture"))))
```

## Define server with information needed to hotlink image

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$picture <-
    renderText({
      c(
        '<img src="',
        "http://www.google.com.tw/search?biw=1536&bih=759&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=notebook+movie&oq=notebook+movie&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l4.5729.7315.0.7708.6.6.0.0.0.0.223.623.4j1j1.6.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.6.622...0i67k1.0.P-BZX3u-bzo#imgrc=S0E91gxvZcgeMM:",
        '">'
      )
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Every movie has different poster images.

Comment: The ideal way is to extract the movie image from imdb or any such repository while the movie detail is loaded or better have all the images downloaded in your local storage and refer to it